# When you roll on the Scart Table, do you use the total value of all the dice, or the highest single value on any of the dice?

Tags: fear, deadlands-classic

When you fail a Guts check, you have to roll on the Scart table with the specified number of dice.

**Do you add up these dice like damage (total across all dice) or like aptitudes (highest value on a single die)?**

The spread of results makes me think you take the total like damage, but that could be just to account for aces (exploding dice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Like Damage

The **Terror** Table lists the resultant Dice rolled on the **Scart Table**. Those dice are not Traits or Aptitudes, and they aren't in the notation of Traits or Aptitudes (i.e. italics). Therefore, nothing in the rules indicates that they would be rolled like Traits and Aptitudes.

The only other way to roll *multiple* dice, in the rules, is like damage and the surrounding text does not list any special rolling instruction.

This is [confirmed](http://weirdwest.pbworks.com/w/page/13646568/weirdwest_scart) in the [accumulated rulings](http://weirdwest.pbworks.com/w/page/13646514/AccumulatedRulings), where Shane himself clarified that the dice are added together.

This does mean that a TN 13 horror has a minimum possible Scart result of "Queasy". But that seems fitting for a horror so nightmarish that it lives in the category beyond "incredible".